# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ftrJSDK in java.library.path

Tags: java, dll

I have a java project which relies on two dll file to run . The name of the dll files are ftrJavaScanAPI.dll and ftrScanAPI.dll .

My OS version is 64 bit . So I want to copy these dll to C:\Windows\System32 location . But after copying these dll to C:\Windows\System32 location , then I am trying to run the project .

In that case , I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ftrJSDK in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.futronic.SDKHelper.FutronicSdkBase.<clinit>(FutronicSdkBase.java:137)
    at com.Futronic.WorkedEx.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:58)
    at com.Futronic.WorkedEx.MainForm$8.run(MainForm.java:717)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I can't  copy these dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 location . If I want to copy them to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 location I am getting the following error :

```
the action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program"
```

After searching a lot in the internet , I have come to know that ftrScanAPI.dll is a windows specific dll . It cant be copied C:\Windows\SysWOW64 location .

I have tried by setting vm options in properties > Run > vm options by the following value :

```
 -Djna.library.path="E:\Sultan\ScanAPI_Java_Sample_v1014-added_GetSN\dlls\x64"
```

But the error is same as above .

I can run this project in 32 bit pc by copying the two dll to C:\Windows\System32 location . For 64 bit pc , where should I copy the twoo dll ? How can I remove the  error ? Please help me .

Comment: why not just specify -Djava.library.path=/path/to/folder/where/dlls/are on the command line

Comment: I have tried this . But the error is same .